# Time difference between day and time

Tags: java, datetime

I am developing a Java Swing application which sends a report on a specific day and time of a week, say for example the  report time is Wed 09:00:00. I am  trying to calculate the time difference between current Day and time with report Time. For example:

DayTime1 = "Wed 09:00:00"
DayTime2 = "Tue 13:00:00"

How do I calculate the time difference between these two values? I tried by myself, but I couldn't even get close to the result.

Comment: if it is Date objects, date1.getTime()-date2.getTime() will give you diff in milliseconds.

Comment: SubinS is right. What format do you want to see the result in?

Comment: You should always post the code you tried, even if it didn't work. It helps demonstrate you've put some effort into the problem and it may provide more information to us than your question. So, please post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create the String into Date objects and then calculate the duration between the two instances.

```
DateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE HH:mm:ss");
Date date1 = dateformat.parse(dayTime1);
Date date2 = dateformat.parse(dayTime2);
getDuration(date1, date2, Calendar.MINUTE);

public static long getDuration(Date returnTime, Date leaveTime, int scale) {
        long durationInMillis = returnTime.getTime() - leaveTime.getTime();
        switch (scale) {
            case Calendar.MINUTE:
                return durationInMillis / ONE_MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
            case Calendar.MILLISECOND:
                return durationInMillis;
            case Calendar.SECOND:
                return durationInMillis / ONE_SECOND_IN_MILLIS;
            case Calendar.HOUR:
                return durationInMillis / ONE_HOUR_IN_MILLIS;
            case Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR:
            case Calendar.DATE:
                return durationInMillis / ONE_DAY_IN_MILLIS;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid scale specified");
    }
```